# Search & Extract the string by comparing every value with all values with in the column (even order of values are different) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a column and I am trying to compare the 1 value with all other values till the last value and extract the matched string even order of values are different .(for ex : Row no.20 and 24) Output data frame will be df_out.

```
Col_1 = c("AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB")
df_input = data.frame(Col_1)
```

Output data frame is as follows

```
Col_1 = c("AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF",  "AB,CD,EF,GH","AB,CD,EF,GH","AB,CD,EF,GH","AB,CD,EF,GH","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","MN,OP","MN,OP","MN,OP","MN,OP", "AB,MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","AB,MN,OP",
          "OP,MN,AB","OP,MN,AB","OP,MN,AB","OP,MN,AB","OP,MN,AB")
Col_2 = c("AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB",  "AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB",  "AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB", "AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB",
          "AB,CD,EF","AB,CD,EF,GH","MN,OP","AB,MN,OP","OP,MN,AB")


match = c("Complete Match","AB,CD","NO Matching","AB","AB","AB,CD","Complete Match","NO Matching","AB","AB","NO Matching","NO Matching","Complete Match",
          "MN,OP","MN,OP","AB","AB","MN,OP","Complete Match","Complete Match","AB","AB","MN,OP","Complete Match","Complete Match")


df_out = data.frame(Col_1,Col_2,match)
```

I have tried with grepl and not able to get the desired output.

Comment: Why is in your expected output the value for `match[2]` == "AB,CD" ad not "AB,CD,EF"? The comparison should be "AB,CD,EF" vs "AB,CD,EF,GH"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a (somewhat messy) solution:

```
funcmatch <- function(a, b) {
  ma <- match(a, b)
  if (all(is.na(ma)))
    return("NO MATCH") 
  else if (sum(!is.na(ma)) == length(b)) 
    return("COMPLETE MATCH") 
  else 
    return(paste0(a[na.omit(ma)], collapse = ",")) 
}

mapply(funcmatch, strsplit(Col_1, ","), strsplit(Col_2, ","))
```

And the solution :

```
 [1] "COMPLETE MATCH" "AB,CD,EF"       "NO MATCH"      
 [4] "AB"             "EF"             "COMPLETE MATCH"
 [7] "COMPLETE MATCH" "NO MATCH"       "AB"            
[10] "EF"             "NO MATCH"       "NO MATCH"      
[13] "COMPLETE MATCH" "OP,NA"          "OP,MN"         
[16] "AB"             "AB"             "COMPLETE MATCH"
[19] "COMPLETE MATCH" "COMPLETE MATCH" "OP"            
[22] "OP"             "COMPLETE MATCH" "COMPLETE MATCH"
[25] "COMPLETE MATCH"
```

Comment: Not messy at all -beautiful!

Comment: Thank you Vincent ,  How can we get Col_1 and Col_2 from Col_1 of df_input data frame (i.e repeat every value with other value)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your follow-up question, can you edit your original question with what you want?

Comment: Thank you Chris, I found it messy as a one-liner, but the extended version that I posted looks OK. Also, I'm not thrilled that it mixes up two different things: the actual "match" and a sort of "similarity" measure (NO MATCH and COMPLETE MATCH), I would have very much liked to put that in a different column, but that does not answer the question.